# Object value calls a function, but all the values for the function trigger when importing object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an issue where I'm importing an object into another file. Object looks like:

```
export const MyObject = { 
      value1: mergeObject({object of data}),
      value2: mergeObject({object of data}),
      ...
};
```

The object values call a function where I'm merging two objects. The issue is that when I'm importing `MyObject` to another file and I'm attempting to access a single value all of the functions for each value fire off.

I anticipated just being able to import the object like normal and access the values like `MyObject.value1`, but the function was being called for every value of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's exactly what this syntax does:

```
{
  value1: mergeObject({object of data}),
  value2: mergeObject({object of data})
}
```

To build this object literal, it is evaluating the expressions for its properties.  It sounds like you want those properties to be *functions*, not *values*.  Something like this:

```
{
  value1: () => mergeObject({object of data}),
  value2: () => mergeObject({object of data})
}
```

And then you'd invoke the function when you want to use it:

```
MyObject.value1()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I tried something like this earlier, but I totally forgot to call the function by adding the `()`.